# How to edit contents of pdf files using php

Tags: php, pdf, edit

I have a PDF file.Which is in non editable format. It contains some 'fill in the blanks' type questions. I want to fill the blanks dynamically using php libraries and save it as pdf. Is there any PHP script to do this?

Comment: I already search in google and didn't get  proper solutions

Answer (score 1):

here are what I suggest

Option 1. You generate your pdf each time it needs to be filled dynamically from php using [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) which I haved used before so I can recommend as good library.After generating and populating your pdf you make it non editable.

Option 2 is to use a similar solution suggested on [stackoverflow](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: user will upload a sample pdf with blank fields. Our requirement is fill those blanks dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.pdfescape.com/open/?E3785799BCCDD64977A5F1E226A361B9DB3A250F187CA3AF

may help you.
It will allow you to upload pdf from your PC and gives options to edit.

Comment: the OP asked for a PHP solution